# How make a certain routers inaccessible without a specific http token using nextjs middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, middleware

I want to achieve 2 things using my middleware :

1- any page that's not /login or /register to be inaccessible without a token

2- if there's a token  and user tries to go to /login , user will be redirected to /

my middleware function is this :

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const token = request.cookies?.get("cookieToken")?.value;
  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();

  if (url.href.endsWith("/register" || url.href.endsWidth("/login"))) {
    return;
  } else if (!url.href.endsWith("/")) {
    if (!token) {
      url.pathname = "/login";
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
  } else {
    if (!token) {
      url.pathname = "/login";
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
  }
    
  if (url.pathname == "/login" && token) {
    url.pathname = "/";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/"],
};
```

to save my token i'm using js-cookie library , I set the token like this :

```
  Cookies.set("cookieToken", d?.access_token);
```

they only part that works is number 2 , number 1 doesn't work even if there's no token saved for the user he'll be able to access all page routes

any help on what I can do in this case and on how to write my middleware function to be cleaner not a bunch of if and else ifs ?

Comment: You need a refactor for your code ? and does your middleware function works as expected ?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to actually mention what's wrong with it , I'll edit my post in a sec

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because I can't see how you are using your middleware in Next.JS pages, also not sure which rendering mechanism you are following for generating pages. So update the question with some code from pages also so I will get an idea of how you are using that middleware.

Comment: @MaheshMore would you like a picture of my pages folder or what exactly would help you ?

Comment: I just wanted to understand how exactly you are using this middleware because this middleware needs to be invoked when the user tries to access any page and that can be achieved by modifying your either `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` which will get invoked before serving the actual page.

Comment: @MaheshMore I'm using this : https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware which is basically one by nextjs that runs on every page without me needing to  invoke it myself , I just need to put in the  correct file path and correct naming